# jquery: fadeIn() and out function works different in IE

Tags: jquery, fade

HTML

```
  <div class="banner">
    <div style="font-size:35px;" class="bannerloop none">slogan 1</div>
    <div style="font-size:35px;" class="bannerloop none">slogan 2</div>
    <div style="font-size:35px;" class="bannerloop none">slogan 3</div>
    <div style="font-size:35px;" class="bannerlast none">last</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.none {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
  var divs = $('.banner').children('.bannerloop');
  var divscnt = divs.length;
  $(divs).delay(2000).each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(3000*index).fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1500, function() {
      if (index = spanscnt - 1) {
        $('.bannerlast').delay(3000*index).fadeIn(1500);
      }
    });
  });
```

GOAL: After all .bannerloop divs are animated, display .bannerlast div.

Works fine in all browsers except IE - it fades out the first div and then stops.

Comment: `if (index = spanscnt - 1) {` should be `if (index = divscnt - 1) {`

Comment: `divs` is allready a JQuery object there is no need to surround it again with `$(divs)`. It's a good practice to add `$` prefix to juqery objects, `divs` => `$divs` so you won't get confused.

Comment: @Zoltan: This was real stupid. Thanks!!!

Comment: Works fine for me, in IE too, but there is another mistake in that same code.  It should be `if (index == divscnt - 1)` (note double =) That should have stopped it working in *all* browsers!

Comment: `$(divs).delay(2000).each( ...` seems like redundant usage of `delay()` as it´s being set within the `each()` loop as well; `$(this).delay(3000*index) ...`

Comment: @Stefan: I need $(divs).delay(2000).each... to delay the start of looping, cause there is another animation running prior to that. No other solutions I found better than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coding mistake occured.

if (index = spanscnt - 1) { should be if (index = divscnt - 1) {

Answer (score 0):

Try this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yBnXT/)**.

```
var index = 0;

function fadeMe()
{
    $('div.banner div.bannerloop:eq('+index+')').delay(3000*index).fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1500,function(){
        index++;
        if(index < $('div.banner div.bannerloop').length) {
            fadeMe();
        }
        else {
            $('div.banner div.bannerlast').delay(3000*index).fadeIn(1500);
        }
    });
}

fadeMe();
```

Not a huge fan of jQuery's delay() function but I tried to replicate what you had. Works fine in all current browsers.